# Need info on Excel and VBA string processing and storage limits -- and suggested workarounds

Tags: string, excel, vba, dna-sequence

According to this [Microsoft blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/excel/archive/2005/09/26/474258.aspx) the max string length per cell is 32k for MS Office 2010; I've also confirmed this via testing. Problem is that I've got strings (DNA sequences) that are well above that length, and I'm matching sub-sequences of DNA on the whole 32k+ sequence that could match anywhere on the main sequence; meaning that I can not simple break the main sequence out into 32k chucks, since I need to be able to string match the "sub-string-sequence" to the entire "main-string-sequence". One thing that is not clear is if VBA supports processing of strings large than 32k, if VBA supports string concatenation in excess of 32k that might be a work around; meaning I chunk the "main-string-sequence" into 32k chunks on a row to the N-th column, then when I need to process a match just concatenate the strings in a row from column 1 to the N-th, process the match, then dump the temp "main-string-sequence" being stored in VBA.

So, basically the issue is MS-Office 2010 only supports strings per cell up to 32k in length, and I've got strings that are much larger than that which need to be processed in whole form in order for the string matching to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VBA dynamic strings (Dim x As String) can hold 2^31 characters, so you should be good there.  I'm not sure why you are writing them to cells.  Unless you need to for some other reason, I would do it all in VBA.  It's not clear where you're getting the strings.

Here's some code that makes a fake 40,000 character DNA sequence and a fake 5 character substring, then finds where one is inside the other.

```
Sub FindDNASubString()

    Dim lRnd As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sMain As String
    Dim sSub As String
    Dim vaLetters As Variant
    Dim lPos As Long

    Const lUPPER As Long = 3
    Const lLOWER As Long = 0

    vaLetters = Array("A", "C", "T", "G")

    'Create fake main string
    For i = 1 To 40000
        lRnd = Int((lUPPER - lLOWER + 1) * Rnd + lLOWER)
        sMain = sMain & vaLetters(lRnd)
    Next i

    'create fake substring
    For i = 1 To 5
        lRnd = Int((lUPPER - lLOWER + 1) * Rnd + lLOWER)
        sSub = sSub & vaLetters(lRnd)
    Next i

    'find position of sub in main
    lPos = InStr(1, sMain, sSub)

    MsgBox "Substring is at position " & lPos

End Sub
```

Comment: (+1 and selected as the answer.) Thanks, that's a super answer based on the info I was able to give -- again, thank you!